# WebSphere MQ v7.1 Security User Credentials

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Linux Server Box running WebSphere MQ Server v7.1:

I have created a user 'mq-user' that belongs to 'mq-users' group in Linux. Then I created a queue manager `QM_TEST`, and used MQSC to issue the following commands to create a queue and set up the security:

```
SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR) PRINCIPAL('mq-user') AUTHADD(ALL)
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PRINCIPAL('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,GET)
SET SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PRINCIPAL('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,PUT)
DEFINE CHANNEL (TEST_CHANNEL) CHLTYPE (SVRCONN) TRPTYPE (TCP) MCAUSER('mq-user')
SET CHLAUTH(TEST_CHANNEL) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) MCAUSER('mq-user')
DEFINE QLOCAL (TEST_QUEUE)
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(TEST_QUEUE) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PRINCIPAL('mq-user') AUTHADD(ALL)
DEFINE LISTENER (TEST_LISTENER) TRPTYPE (TCP) CONTROL (QMGR) PORT (1414)
START LISTENER (TEST_LISTENER)
```

Linux Client Box running WebSphere MQ Client v7.1 and WebSphere MQ Explorer:

I am logged in as my username (arrehman) which is not part of mq-users group. However I am able to access the queue I created above both via a Java Application and via MQ Explorer client **without passing any user credentials**. Why is it this way if security is in effect?

Any further details needed, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

`SET CHLAUTH(TEST_CHANNEL) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) MCAUSER('mq-user')`

Says the following:

- For connections requesting `TEST_CHANNEL`...
- Originating from *any* IP address...
- Set the MCAUSER to `mq-user`

In other words, enable the channel such that any connections inherit the privileges of `mq-user` regardless of where they originate and what identity they present.  So the behavior you are seeing is the expected behavior based on the `CHLAUTH` rule above.

There are a few other problems with the rules as listed:

- The use of `PRINCIPAL` rather than `GROUP`.  On non-windows servers if you specify `PRINCIPAL` what happens is that the QMgr looks up that ID, queries its primary group and then sets authorizations based on that.  So if `mq-users` has a primary group of `staff` or `users` that that is what gets authorized instead of `mq-users` and is probably not what you intended.  Always use `group` so that you get the result you intend with `setmqaut` or `AUTHREC`.
- Granting `ALL` on the QMgr makes the ID/group administrative.  One of the privileges at the QMgr level is `SET` and any user in a group with `SET` rights can set, among other things, authorization control lists.  So even though you only granted `AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,PUT)` the `mq-users` ID can submit PCF commands to grant all access to all objects.  Only grant `CONNECT` and `INQUIRE` on the QMgr if that's all you need.
- There's an assumption stated (in bold, actually) that you would have expected to be required to pass user credentials.  Please be aware that WMQ does not validate a user ID and password if you do provide them.  It accepts the ID that you assert.  The password field is available to exits which can be used to validate the ID and password against, for example, LDAP or the local OS.  Such an exit can be purchased from a 3rd party or written but base WMQ doesn't do anything with the password.  Had you specified `USERSRC(CHANNEL)` on the mapping, then your ID would have been used and most likely rejected.  But the rejection would have been either because it is in the `mqm` group (which is blocked by a default `CHLAUTH` rule) or because there are no `AUTHREC` records for the group it is in.

For more about hardening WMQ, there are a number of resources collected [here](http://t-rob.net/links).  The *Hardening WebSphere MQ* presentation is from v7.0.  Although v7.1 has new controls, the principals remain the same:

- Authenticate the connection using IP filtering (for apps or QMgrs where the connection originates in a locked datacenter), SSL/TLS and/or an exit
- Map the authenticated identity to an `MCAUSER` value by hard-coding it in the channel or by using an exit or `CHLAUTH` rule to dynamically set it
- Administrative connections and high-value applications should be authenticated using TLS

Comment: T.Rob, the question was written with your response in mind. Fabulous job as usual, I will fix up the issues as you suggested. This make me feel a lot better now regarding security. I am going to read up the 'hardening security' article, if I have questions I will post it here. Thanks!

Comment: I gave all combiniations of BROWSE,CLR,CONNECT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,SETALL to the queue manager, however MQ Explorer fails to connect to it, which authorization is what I am missing? If I give ALL it works.

Comment: Are you sure you are authorizing the right objects?  I just whipped up a QMgr and granted `+inq` `+dsp` `+connect` and it worked fine. On the other hand, `+browse` `+get` and others that don't apply to the QMgr result in an error `AMQ7097: You gave an authorization specification that is not valid.`

Comment: My bad, I don't know how I managed that! It is good now, thanks Rob.

Comment: We'll chalk that one up to gremlins. ;-)  Glad it's working now!